# VB change color border menustrip

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

I add a menustrip in my application and I want change border color on the menustrip. I have found some code but you can see on the picture I have a border again.

Picture :

[image]

My code :

```
Public Class ColorTable
    Inherits ProfessionalColorTable

    Dim Color1 = Color.FromArgb(30, 38, 44)
    Dim Color2 = Color.FromArgb(75, 81, 88)

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuBorder() As Color
        Get
            Return Color1
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin() As Color
        Get
            Return Color2
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd() As Color
        Get
            Return Color2
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelected() As Color
        Get
            Return Color2
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemBorder() As Color
        Get
            Return Color1
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemPressedGradientBegin() As Color
        Get
            Return Color2
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemPressedGradientEnd() As Color
        Get
            Return Color2
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Menus.Renderer = New ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(New ColorTable())
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to *change* the border color or *remove* the border.  The question is no clear.  It looks like the code is working as written

Comment: I want remove the white border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to also override the following properties:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SeparatorDark() As Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ToolStripDropDownBackground() As Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property
```

This will cover the background and any separators you happen to add.

Comment: Thank you for your help now I have this :

http://image.prntscr.com/image/086ee3794d5d4471a6df7e7531afb000.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have add

```
        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientBegin() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return Color1
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientEnd() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return Color1
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientMiddle() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return Color1
        End Get
    End Property
```

And now all is ok :)