# VB change color border menustrip but from external class

Tags: vb.net, overriding, menustrip

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710553/vb-change-color-border-menustrip) on how change the colors in the menu.
My question is related to the above old solution.

I can confirm that the solution worked fine on vb.net 2015 with framework 4.6.2

Color1 and Color 2 are inside the class.

Question is: how I can use Color1 and Color 2 from form_load1?

Let me report here the full code found (there are 2 answer and here is joint)

```
Public Class ColorTable
Inherits ProfessionalColorTable

Dim Color1 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#343D46")
Dim Color2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#424B54")

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuBorder() As Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin() As Color
    Get
        Return Color2
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd() As Color
    Get
        Return Color2
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelected() As Color
    Get
        Return Color2
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemBorder() As Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemPressedGradientBegin() As Color
    Get
        Return Color2
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemPressedGradientEnd() As Color
    Get
        Return Color2
    End Get
End Property
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SeparatorDark() As Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ToolStripDropDownBackground() As Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientBegin() As System.Drawing.Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientEnd() As System.Drawing.Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientMiddle() As System.Drawing.Color
    Get
        Return Color1
    End Get
End Property
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Menus.Renderer = New ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(New ColorTable())
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean setting the colors (color1, color2) in the `Load` event? or just access them? Both scenarios, you need to keep the `ColorTable` instance in a class field. To set the colors, make color1 and color2 public properties to get and set them. Or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: See how the `MenuDesigner` class works here: [Change space between Image and Text in ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130479/7444103); it's used (among the other things) to setup the colors of a `ProfessionalColorTable` and change them on the fly when needed (or requested by the user for customizations)

Comment: @dr.null
I would like set the properties Color1 and Color 2 from Form1_Load

Comment: In `ColorTable` class replace `Dim Color1 = ..` with `Public Property Color1 As Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#343D46")`. Do the same for `Color2`. In `Form1`, add class field like: `Private ReadOnly MyColorTable As New ColorTable`, in `Load` event, set the colors `MyColorTable.Color1 = ...`, use this instance to create the renderer. `Menus.Renderer = New ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(MyColorTable)`

Comment: @dr.null
Perfect! I have done it and it worked great! Thanks!